# Matching Specific URL pattern for redirection

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm moving from blogspot to my own website (joomla), so I need a redirection for the URLs with "blogspot"-structure to my new website (that is the Home page = mydomain.com), in order for my existing links not to become broken links.

The current blogspot URLs are of this structure:
www.mydomain.com/{year}/{month}/{article-alias}
(e.g. www.mydomain.com/2016/04/article.html)

I want to match everything that starts with a number after .com/ and then redirect to simply www.mydomain.com (only the domain).
I have no touch with regex and I would like to ask for your input in order to do it right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/^www.mydomain.com\/[\d]+.*/` should match anything with one or more digits (the [\d] means [0-9]) following the .com/, but including something like  www.mydomain.com/2015-was-the-best. If you want to make it more strict you could change it to something like `/^www.mydomain.com\/[\d]+\/.*/` (any number(s) followed by a slash), or `/^www.mydomain.com\/[\d]{4}\/.*/` (four numbers followed by a slash).

Comment: Thanks Max! I tried it but did not work... Do I have to rename htaccess.txt  to  .htaccess ?

Comment: I don't know much (or anything? hehe) about the redirect/htaccess part of the question; I can only say that the one time years ago that I used htaccess stuff for simple logins, it was an .htaccess file. Hope you figure it out.